# How to find the line-width of a laser from a beat-note?

Tags: laser

If I have 2 lasers that have the same specifications and are more or less identical, and then take the beat note of these 2 lasers I am supposed to be able to gain valuable information about the laser such as its line-width. However, I don't understand the math behind it. I know the line-width can be taken as the Full Width Half Maximum of the Power spectral density curve. But I'm not sure how the PSD is related to the beat-note.

Can someone give me an explanation of how the line-width is calculated from the beatnote?

Comment: "I am supposed to" ─ according to whom? I.e. what text are you reading. As in your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/341547/) (but less so), this is missing some context. Normally, I would expect the frequency of the beat note to indicate the frequency difference between the two lasers, and little else; the information about the coherence (including the linewidth) will be encoded in the details of the oscillation (e.g. things like the contrast of the beat) but that depends on exactly what you're measuring. So, again, more context would help.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty according to some reading I've done on the internet (https://www.rp-photonics.com/linewidth.html) that fails to give me a detailed explanation of mathematically how to do it. I'm sorry I can't give you better context. Much of it lies within my own confusion on the topic. I was under the impression that the linewidth of a laser could be found through the beatnote. If I'm wrong, it would be greatly appreciated if I could be informed as to the tools and methods for finding the linewidth.

Comment: Being confused is OK, but just saying "I'm confused" and throwing up your arms in surrender makes it much harder to get help. As an example, the RP Photonics article you linked to makes it very explicit that "measure the linewidth of a laser" is a *very* vague goal, because the solution will vary wildly depending on the situation. You seem to have already chosen one of the solutions, which implies that you've already factored in constraints and details about your experiment that inform the implementation but which are absent from the post.

Comment: Alternatively, if your question is just "X resource mentions Y method for doing Z under U and V conditions and the constraint that W, but I'm confused about how exactly that method works", then just say that - and do fill in the gaps as indicated. Are you asking about the general method? then say so. Are you asking about a specific implementation? Then give the relevant details about the sources involved.

Comment: Did you click through from the page you linked to the one about [Self-heterodyne Linewidth Measurement](https://www.rp-photonics.com/self_heterodyne_linewidth_measurement.html)?

Comment: I lack a lot of knowledge on this topic and so for the time being I am much more concerned with the theory of it all than the constraints and details of experiments. I chose that method because that's the method I've been asked to base my findings on (I am an intern). I'm not "throwing my arms up in surrender". I genuinely do not know specific constraints or conditions concerning that method. I was simply using it as a platform to help guide my understanding. I apologize for any misunderstanding. I'll be back with another question to better reflect my needs.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes I have read that. It says "From this signal, the laser linewidth can then be calculated." I would like to know how

Comment: The key sentence is "[when] the superimposed beams are essentially uncorrelated, and the output spectrum becomes a simple self-convolution of the laser output spectrum [1]". (The "self" part because this is describing self-heterodyning. If you're heterodyning two sources you don't have to worry about the coherence length issue and you just get the beat note spectrum being the convolution of the two input signals' spectra) From there you can either work out the math, or go to the citation in *Electronics Letters*.